# Can we get custom dtype from pandas dataframe column?

Tags: pandas

Can we get custom dtype from pandas column or at least order of encoded values ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"b": [1, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan], "a": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b"]})
ordered = pd.CategoricalDtype(["a", "b"], ordered=True)
df["a"].astype(ordered)
df.dtypes
# a     object
# b    float64
# dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign the output:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(ordered)
print(df.dtypes)
```

output:

```
b     float64
a    category
dtype: object
```

Alternative, use [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) with the `dtype` parameter:

```
df['a'] = pd.Categorical(df['a'], dtype=ordered)
```